# Form Data not refreshing with newest entries

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

When I add a new customer in customer table and access AddOrderForm form, I don't get the new customer in the choices.But on server restart I am able to get the new customer in the choices list.Any reason ?

Customer Table

```
class Customer(db.Model):
     id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
     email = db.Column(db.String(120), unique=True)
     mobile_num = db.Column(db.String(13), unique=True)
     name = db.Column(db.String(120))
     marketing_source = db.Column(db.String(120))
     date_of_birth = db.Column(db.DateTime)
     gender = db.Column(db.String(13))
     store_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('store.id'))

     def __init__(self,email,mobile_num,name,marketing_source,date_of_birth, gender,store_id):
         self.email = email
         self.mobile_num = mobile_num
         self.name = name
         self.marketing_source = marketing_source
         self.date_of_birth = date_of_birth
         self.gender = gender
         self.store_id = store_id
     def __repr__(self):
          return '%r, %s ' % (self.name.encode('utf-8'), self.mobile_num)
```

AddOrderForm

```
class AddOrderForm(Form):
    order_id  = TextField('Website Order Id', [validators.length(min=4, max=120)])
    item_name = TextField('Item Name', [validators.length(min=4, max=120)])
    item_cost = DecimalField('Item Cost' , [validators.Required()])
    custmer_id = SelectField('Customer',coerce=int,choices= convert_list_wtforms_choices(Customer.query.all()))
    order_category = SelectField('Order Category',coerce=int,choices=[(1,'Mobiles'), (2,'Clothing')])
    linq_shipping_cost =  DecimalField('Linq Shipping Cost' , [validators.Required()])
    website_shipping_cost = DecimalField('Website Shipping Cost' , [validators.Required()])
    advance_amount = DecimalField('Advance Amount' , [validators.Required()])
    website = SelectField('Website', coerce=int,choices=[(1,'Amazon'), (2,'Flipkart')] )
    other = TextField('Any Other Information')
```

While accessing the form from a view I don't get the latest added customer in the  custmer_id choices. Any idea to fix this?

Comment: The new customer doesn't appear when you refresh the page the form is on either?  Because if you have the form on the same page you are creating a new customer and that page isn't refreshed it makes sense you won't see the customer right?  The page loads all current customers in the DB into the form (at this time your new customer doesn't exist).

Comment: I am accessing AddOrderForm after I have entered the customer. Essentially the new customer is already in the database.I have verified it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're only setting the choices once, when you define the form.  Instead, re-select them every time you instantiate the form.

```
class AddOrderForm(Form):
    customer_id = SelectField('Customer', coerce=int)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(AddOrderForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.customer_id.choices = convert_list_wtforms_choices(Customer.query.all())
```